# What do nested resources in rails routes do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've run into some code that looks like this:

```
resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
  resources :comments, only: [:show, :create] do
  end
end
```

I know what `resources` does (it automatically creates some restful routes) and I know what `only` does (it limits which ones to include only), but I have no idea what nesting resources inside other resources does.

Does this actually *do anything* to the project or is it just good practice to nest them so you can see how they are related?

In other words, would this accomplish exactly the same thing?:

```
resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show]
resources :comments, only: [:show, :create]
```

Comment: do you need any more clarification on the question? Just let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not produce the exact same thing.

You can actually try it and see the `rake routes` output.

What first option means, that there is a model `Post`, which has a `has_many` association with model `Comment` (`Comment` model here is a child for `Post`).

With this option you can view and create certain `post`'s comment(s). See more details [in docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

First option would generate routes like following:

```
/posts/:post_id/comments/comment_id
```

But in second option you will not have such opportunity, because the routes are unrelated.

Generated routes here would look like

```
/posts/:post_id/
/comments/comment_id
```

Comment: please comment on your downvotes - do not be afraid - be constructive.

Comment: Does nested resources only affect routes, or other things too?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this useful guide on routing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

> It's common to have resources that are logically children of other resources. For example, suppose your application includes these models:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :ads    
end     

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :magazine    
end
```

> Nested routes allow you to capture this relationship in your routing. In this case, you could include this route declaration:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

> In addition to the routes for magazines, this declaration will also route ads to an AdsController. The ad URLs require a magazine

Comment: answers with just a link, even though it may be helpful, does not constitute a good answer.  in addition to providing a link, you should also quote the source, with relevant content to the OP

Comment: minus the improper indentation and line breaks - yes :)  vote removed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [`RESTful architecture`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). If you understand it, it will be much clearer why you should nest resources.

As the name already says, `resources` are somehow records in the database. So for example `Users`, `cars`, `tasks` and so on. But of course your aren't restricted to just have one of them.

Sometimes however, resources belong to other. So for example a user `has many` cars or tasks or whatever. Since a task won't belong to another user we nesting them into the user's resource.

```
resources :users do
    resources :cars
    resources :tasks
end
```

This will make sense since a task or car will, for at least this application, belong to just one user.

You can of course also nest deeper than just one level. You could do something like this:

```
resources :users do
    resources :lists do
        resources :tasks do
            resources :likes    # The social task sheet :)
        end
    end
end
```

But it isn't good practice since it creates long unmaintainable URLs which look like this:

```
http://example.com/users/1/lists/124/tasks/25/likes/2124
```

This is horrible to maintain.

But if you use scoping right than it brings huge advantages like better and more scalable `Authorization` or less code duplication.

It's also really convenient for the different responses. For example if you strictly follow `CRUD` you controller should just `create`, `read`, `update` and `destroy` one type of resource. This works well till the point where you want additional features.

For example you have a `post` resource. Later you decide you want to add a `like` (resource) feature. You shouldn't put them all into the `PostController` now since it's just for the `posts` responsible. You should do something like I mentioned above or this:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :likes
end
```

Now you have a `PostsController` which is responsible for `posts` and a `LikesController` that's responsible for the `likes` of the post. It wouldn't make sense to give them their own `scope` since they belong to a `post`.

I hope it's a little bit more understandable why you should nest resources.